# How to pass message with a stream value in different events of a bloc?

Tags: firebase, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web, flutter-bloc

See the bloc below,

```
class ProfileBloc extends Bloc<ProfileEvents, ProfileStates> {
  Firestore database = Firestore();
  FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  StreamSubscription _subscription;

  ProfileBloc() : super(ProfileAppStartState());

  @override
  Stream<ProfileStates> mapEventToState(ProfileEvents event) async* {
    if (event is ProfileInitialEvent) {
      if (firebaseAuth.currentUser != null) {
        User firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.currentUser;
        Stream<MakaniUser> makaniUser = database.getUserData(firebaseUser.uid);

        await _subscription?.cancel();
        _subscription = makaniUser.listen((user) => add(
            ProfileDataReceivedEvent(user: user, message: 'Data Received')));
      }
    } else if (event is ProfileUpdateMobileEvent) {
      if (firebaseAuth.currentUser != null) {
        User firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.currentUser;
        await database.updateUserPhoneNumber(event.phoneNumber);
        Stream<MakaniUser> makaniUser = database.getUserData(firebaseUser.uid);

        await _subscription?.cancel();
        _subscription = makaniUser.listen((user) => add(
            ProfileDataReceivedEvent(
                user: user, message: 'mobile updated')));
      }
    } else if (event is ProfileDataReceivedEvent) {
      yield ProfileDataReceivedState(user: event.user, message: event.message);
    }
  }
}
```

Now I presume this is a very bad approach to get Stream of user data from database on every event. Is there a way so that I do not have to get stream every time, sending the different messages on different events?